# How to properly convert HEX to BIN in PHP7?

Tags: php, type-conversion, hex, bin

I am trying to convert HEX value "0000" into BIN value.
In math:
(0000)16 = (0000 0000 0000 0000)2

but when I am trying to use

```
$hex = '0000';
echo base_convert ($hex, 16, 2);
```

I am getting 0 insted of 0000 0000 0000 0000.

It looks the same but is not.
In my scenario, the 16 bits represent the status of digital outputs saved as HEX value.

What do I need to change, to make it work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting 0 because `base_convert` will not output any more digits into the result string than are necessary to represent the number. Instead, use [`hexdec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php) to convert the string to a decimal number and then use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to get the output as 16 binary digits using the `%b` conversion specification:

```
$hex = '0000';
$bin = sprintf("%016b", hexdec($hex));
echo $bin;
```

Output:

```
0000000000000000
```

If you really want spaces between each block of 4 bits, you can use [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) e.g.

```
echo implode(' ', str_split($bin, 4)) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/NRoFS)

Comment: @Tikky I've improved the answer, removing the call to `base_convert` and replacing it with `hexdec` which is more appropriate to use with `sprintf`.

Comment: than you once again. Works fine for me

Answer (score -1):

PHP and Js have the same problem in my experience. I used to check and add n 0 where needed.

Comment: This is not what `hex2bin` is for. If you had created a demo example e.g. https://3v4l.org/BqpBu you would see that it does not produce the output OP wants.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me :) I did not read the question thoroughly.